# Nested "bi-directional" slots in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs-slots

I'm using Vuejs.
I created two components: `First` and `Second`.

1. `First` renders `Second`.
2. `Second` has a named slot.
3. `First` contains a `<template>`, to go into `Second`'s named slot.
4. Inside `First`'s `<template>` - there is another named slot.
5. Inside `Second`'s `<slot>` - there is a `<template>`, to go into `First`'s `<template>`'s named slot.

What I get is `First`'s `<template>` rendered inside `Second`'s slot.

It's correct, but I would like to also see `Second`'s `<template>` rendered inside the `<slot>` of `First`'s `<template>`. But I don't.

Here is the code:

```
var First = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div>
      In first<br/>
      <second>
        <template slot="slot1">
          In template of First
          <slot name="slot2">
          </slot>
        </template>
      </second>
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('first', First)

var Second = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div>
      In second<br/>
      <slot name="slot1">
        <template slot="slot2">
          In template of Second
        </template>
      </slot>
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component('second', Second)
```

Here is the output:

```
In first
In second
In template of First
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/obeobe/f98kr4ye/

I would like to get this output:

```
In first
In second
In template of First
In template of Second
```

Can I achieve this with slots? If not, can it be achieved in another way, but without creating a third component?

**EDIT**: a possible real-life use-case: a List component that allows the HTML content of each item to be defined by its host, and can inject some content of its own inside the host's content, at a spot designated by the host.

For example, something like this:

Host component:

```
<div class="myList">
    <list v-bind:items="usersArray">
        <template slot="itemSlot" slotScope="item">
            <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
            <div>{{ item.country }}</div>
            <div>{{ item.phone }}</div>
            <slot name="actions"> <--------- the spot for the List component to inject generic actions
            </slot>
            <div>{{ item.age }}</div>
        </template>
    </list>
</div>
```

"List" component:

```
<div>
    <div v-for="(anItem, idx) in items">
        <div>{{ idx }}</div>
        <slot name="itemSlot" v-bind:item="anItem">
            <template slot="actions">
                <a v-on:click="duplicateItem(anItem)">Duplicate</a> <---------- the "duplicateItem" method would be implemented inside this List component
                <a>Edit</a>
                <a>Delete</a>
            </template>
        </slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @obe I just add my answer, it sounds a bit silly to me so not sure I understand your condition correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no bi-directional slots in Vue.js

```html
<div id="app">
  <first>
         ─────────────────────┐
  </first>                    │
</div>                        │
                              │
<div>                         │
  In first<br/>               │
  <second>                    │
    <template slot="slot1">  ─────┐
      In template of First    │   │
      <slot name="slot2">  <──┘ ┄┄│┄┄> This slot will replaced by slot2
      </slot>                     │    template child of first component.
    </template>                   │
  </second>                       │
</div>                            │
                                  │
<div>                             │
  In second<br/>                  │
  <slot name="slot1">  <──────────┘
    <template slot="slot2">  ┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄> This is fallback content it will 
      In template of Second            shows up if no content provided.
    </template>                        But slot template is used so
                                       this will go to replace slot2
                                       inside slot.
  </slot>
</div>
```

Since there is no `slot2` or any slot define inside `slot` component so your `In template of Second` would never shows up.

In your example In my opinion there is no way to achieve that. Alternative way to achieve that is bind `duplicateItem` via slot scope.

```js
<div class="myList">
  <list v-bind:items="usersArray">
    <template slot="itemSlot" slotScope="{ item, duplicateItem }">
      <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
      <div>{{ item.country }}</div>
      <div>{{ item.phone }}</div>
      <div>
        <a v-on:click="duplicateItem(item)">Duplicate</a>
        <a>Edit</a>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </div>
      <div>{{ item.age }}</div>
    </template>
  </list>
</div>

<div>
  <div v-for="(anItem, idx) in items">
    <div>{{ idx }}</div>
      <slot name="itemSlot"
        v-bind:item="anItem"
        v-bind:duplicateItem="duplicateItem">
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it inside... I just shared a simplified version...

Comment: @obe Could you explain more detail about that?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and added a more detailed example. I hope it makes things clearer...

Comment: @obe I have updated my answer which you probably already thought of this method as well but I think this is the best method.

Comment: Yes, but I would like the List component to also handle the HTML of the actions... it repeats again and again in different places, so it would be convenient for the List component to own the generic part of the actions area - HTML, logic, and also CSS. Anyway, your answer is not the holy grail I was hoping for, but I do believe that it answers my question correctly in that Vuejs doesn't allow this, and it contains a valid suggestion, so I'm accepting it. Thanks!